# How to automatically load data in an R package?

Tags: r, package

This is likely an easy answer that's been answered numerous times.  I just lack the terminology to search for the answer.

I'm creating a package.  When the package loads I want to have instant access to the data sets.

So lets say DICTIONARY is a data set.

I want to be able to do `DICTIONARY` rather than `data(DICTIONARY)` to get it to load.  How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You should look at packages that succeed in making their datasets available in that manner. For example the MASS dataset Aids2 is available without using data().

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From R-exts.pdf ([online source](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages)):

> The ‘data’ subdirectory is for data files, either to be made available
>   via lazy-loading or for loading using data(). (The choice is made by
>   the ‘LazyData’ field in the ‘DESCRIPTION’ file: the default is not to
>   do so.)

Adding the following to the DESCRIPTION file should do it:

```
LazyData: true
```